# how stop timer task.delay in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, timer

my android app running  slow.Operation like Navigation, is particularly very slow.i used timer by below codes.now i want stop timer when i click button ?how do it

```
void ChangedData()
{
    Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ChangedData();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

}
```

Comment: if you want a Timer you can control why not use the actual Timer class?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Timers;

Timer timer = new Timer(500);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { ChangedData(); };
timer.Start();

// to stop the Timer
timer.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CancellationTokenSource somewhere in your code.

```
var _cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
```

Then call Task.Delay with CancellationToken pass in the method.

```
Task.Delay(500, _cts.Token)
```

To cancel the task, just call Cancel method of the CancellationTokenSource

```
_cts.Cancel();
```

When the task is cancelled, it will throw TaskCanceledException. Please remember to catch the exception.

```
try
{
    Task.Delay(500, _cts.Token).ContinueWith(t =>
        {

            ChangedData();

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    // Handle when task is cancelled.
}
```